How to connect Laravel Application with ZKteco device
I have brough a new ZKteco finger print device and have a attendance management software based on laravel now I want to integrate it with my software I have seen the Doc it is only for C,C# and Java
I have tried many other composer packages but they are not working properly?

You will probably need to write an application in one of the supported languages and call it from PHP.

You can use the BioTime v8.5, recently I used it, the BioTime software can be used as centralized attendance system then it has some good APIs to fetch / send data from / to your laravel app.

Use the ZKteco Push API as documented at https://zkteco.uk/api/index.htm, which enables communication with the biometric machine without using BioTime software. Please note that this API is a paid, licensed service.
